# When page load accordion open all li

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using a jQuery accordion - here my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul#accordion a.heading').click(function() {
        $(this).css('outline','none');
        if($(this).parent().hasClass('current')) {
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp('slow',function() {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('current');
                $.scrollTo('#accordion',1000);
            });
        } else {
            $('ul#accordion li.current ul').slideUp('slow',function() {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('current');
            });
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle('slow',function() {
                $(this).parent().toggleClass('current');
            });
            $.scrollTo('#accordion',1000);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Problem is I want to open 1 li when page loads. But its open all li. And here is my PHP code, 1 li categories and second lis categories item.

```
<ul id="accordion">     
    <?php
        $cates=mysql_query('select * from categories order by id desc limit 10');
        while($gets=mysql_fetch_array($cates)) {
            $title=$gets['title'];
            $id=$gets['id'];
    ?>
    <li class="account">
    <?php 
    echo '<a style="text-decoration:none; color:orange;" href="#'.$title.'" class="heading account nav-user">'.$title.'</a>
    <ul id="'.$title.'">';
        $ads=mysql_query('select * from items where cid="'.$id.'" order by id desc limit 4');
        while($items=mysql_fetch_array($ads)){
            $item=$items['product_name'];
            $adid=$items['id'];
            $stringq = strip_tags($item);
            if (strlen($stringq) > 23) {
                $stringCutq = substr($stringq, 0,25);
                $stringq = substr($stringCutq, 0, strrpos($stringCutq, ' ')).'....'; 
            }
            echo '<li  class="submenu"><a style="text-decoration:none;color:grey;" href="addetail.php?id='.$adid.'">'.$stringq.'</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Also if anyone has best accordion jQuery give me I really appreciate and forgot to tell you this script include jQuery ui.js file. which is big that's not past here hope my problem is solves here.

Comment: well.... are you hiding them by default? if not, that would explain why they were all open. I don't see any indication that you're hiding them by default. Asking for plugin suggestions is not allowed here.

Comment: actualy where i download this accordion script it work fine like when page load then just open 1 li. but not work with me. yes i want to slide up all except 1st li. and when i click another li then 1st close and open where i click